# Add lookupfield using powershell

Tags: powershell, pnp-powershell, pnp-provision

I would like to add a lookupfield as a sitecolumn using PowerShell...but I don't want to use xml definition. Anybody has a solution using pnp cmdlets ?

Thx

Comment: What’s wrong using xml for the field definition? I think that add-pnpfield does not support creating a lookup column for now and you have to use xml for the moment.

Comment: As @Christoffer mentioned, `Add-PnPField` doesn't support creating lookup as it doesn't have necessary parameters. For creating lookup field, we need `Lookup` list. That is currently not supported.`Add-PNPFieldFromXml` is the way to go.